# 403 - Forbidden - Failed to retrieve appliable Sku categories for the user when trying to add team to Microsoft 365 group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

In some cases I get the above mentioned response from the MS Graph API when trying to add Teams to an MS 365 group by doing an HTTP PUT to the endpoint [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupId}/team](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7BgroupId%7D/team).

I have had the same code doing this for a couple of years, and it only started failing a couple of weeks ago - so I suspect MS have changed something related to this at their end.

This does not seem to happen consistently - for some groups the call succeeds, for some it fails. The identities used for making the call are owners of the groups in question and have the **Group.ReadWrite.All** and **Directory.ReadWrite.All** permissions and this has been consented by Global Admin. In some cases when the call fails for one identity it will succeed when doing the call as another identity. In some cases it will fail for all the identities I have tried.

I will normally be doing these calls using the GraphServiceClient in C# where the calling identity is a service principal, but to rule out problems with that I also tried the same in the MS Graph Explorer with the same result - here I use a normal user identity with the correct permissions.

Any similar experiences or suggestions to help resolve this would be highly appreciated

Comment: The error might occur if the **owner** of those Microsoft 365 groups does not have an active Office 365 license assigned. Could you please check and confirm if that's the case?

Comment: Hi @Sridevi - the accounts I do this with are owners of the groups - I'll add that clarification to the question, thank you

Comment: Please check whether the **Owners** of failed groups have valid `Office 365` license or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error usually occurs if the **Owners** of Microsoft 365 group does not have *valid* Office 365 license assigned, while adding team to group.

When I tried to create team from MS 365 group with **Owners** not having active Office 365 license, I too got **same error**:

```json
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/groupId/team
{
    "memberSettings": {
        "allowCreatePrivateChannels": true,
        "allowCreateUpdateChannels": true
    },
    "messagingSettings": {
        "allowUserEditMessages": true,
        "allowUserDeleteMessages": true
    },
    "funSettings": {
        "allowGiphy": true,
        "giphyContentRating": "strict"
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to assign active **Office 365** license to Owners of M365 groups like this:

*Go to Azure Portal -> Microsoft Entra ID -> Groups -> All groups -> Select group -> Owners -> Select Owner -> Licenses -> Assignments*

[image]

When I tried to create team from MS 365 group with **Owner** having active Office 365 license. I got **response** like this:

```json
PUT https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/groupId/team
{
    "memberSettings": {
        "allowCreatePrivateChannels": true,
        "allowCreateUpdateChannels": true
    },
    "messagingSettings": {
        "allowUserEditMessages": true,
        "allowUserDeleteMessages": true
    },
    "funSettings": {
        "allowGiphy": true,
        "giphyContentRating": "strict"
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I follow you there, but the calling identity which owns the group is a service principal which as far as I know cannot be assigned an MS365 license - I'll put that in my question too

Comment: In that case, you need to add at least 1 user with active **Office 365** license as Owner of those groups.

Comment: hmm... that's strange. There were already two other normal users with the necessary licenses owning the groups. Now I tried adding a third - and now it works. I don't get why it stopped working in the first place and I don't get why I have to add and extra user with a license, but it works and that's all I care about - thank you for your help :)